# Git Status that doesn't go crazy if I'm in the wrong directory

Tags: git

Using git in windows powershell, when I navigate to a new directory, a lot of the time I'll check `git status` and then `git remote update` to check the status of the work saved there.

If I'm in a directory that doesn't actually have a repo initialized in it, git goes to the top of the directory tree and lists every untracked file in the tree, basically it goes ballistic and lists hundreds or thousands of files.

I see how that would be useful behavior in a different situation where I was in the subdirectory of a repo directory , but is there a different command I should start with instead of `status`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not standard behaviour. Normally you'd get something like

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

You probably have a Git repository somewhere up the directory tree. Try running

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

when you believe you're outside of a repository (and when `git status` shows every untracked file as you describe). This should show you the directory that contains a repository.

If you're sure that you don't want a repo in that directory you can just delete its `.git/` subdirectory. **This will remove all of the history, so be careful!**

Comment: ah good point, I bet I do have a throw-away repo in a directory like `documents` or something, thanks

Comment: I was about to post a very suboptimal answer with an alias to embed a `cd` before the `status`, but 1) I struggled with the powershell syntax that I don't use at work and 2) your answer came right on time to nail it. Far better to understand the cause and deal with it than curing the wound forever :-)

Comment: yeah, I honestly only use compatible linux commands in powershell, cmdlets haven't caught on for me yet